# Line created using tcDrawLine is not displaying properly

Tags: activex, teechart

We want to create a vertical line with dashed style. We used the code below to draw the line. The line is not being displayed on the Chart until we don't manually refresh the dialog box. We included the below logic inside OnAfterDrawTchart event. Please provide your input. Source code:

```
long lDrawLineTool = m_reschedChart.GetTools().Add(tcDrawLine);
CDrawLineTool cDrawLineTool = Chart.GetTools().GetItems(lDrawLineTool).GetAsDrawLine();
cDrawLineTool.AddLine(5, 0, 5, 10);
cDrawLineTool.GetPen().SetStyle(psDash);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After initializing the chart you'll probably have to call [InternalRepaint](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/activex/lib/html/teec3i0k.htm) method. For example:

```
m_reschedChart.GetEnvironment().InternalRepaint();
```

so that OnAfterDraw event is fired.

Comment: We are already calling InternalRepaint method after initialization of chart. problem is first time when we open chart, vertical line is displaying on chart. after that when we move or maximize or minimize our dialog vertical line stop displaying on chart. again if we perform above operation(move,maximize,minimize), it start displaying on chart. every alternate move it is start displaying.

Comment: @Prabhat what about adding InternalRepaint at the OnResize event or any other event that may be involved?

Comment: How can we calculate below mention coordinates in chart using teechart API ?
yscale = y axis length / ( yaxis max - y axis min)
yOffset = y origin - y axis min * yscale.

Comment: @Prabhat that looks like an entire new question to me. Can you please submit a new question with more detailed information? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added InternalRepaint on Resize event, it resolved my issue. Thanks.